# Azure AD Authentication with Custom Authorization in ASP.Net Core 6

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization

I have implemented the Azure AD Authentication in ASP.Net Core 6 using the standard way and have used the [Authorize] attribute on top of the controller class. All these are working fine.

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

Apart from the Authentication, I am trying to build the custom Authorization using TypeFilterAttribute class. Code snippet below:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(params Roles[] roles) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        Roles[] _roles = roles;
        Arguments = new object[] { _roles };
    }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly Roles[] _roles;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(Roles[] roles, IUserService userService)
    {
        _roles = roles ?? throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("OnAuthorization : Missing role parameter");
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.HttpContext != null &&
            context.HttpContext.User != null &&
            context.HttpContext.User.Identity != null)
        {
            string? userEmailId = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmailId))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "OnAuthorization : Invalid User : Email Id is not present",
                    StatusCode = 401
                };

                return;
            }

            var userDetails = await _userService.GetUserProfile(userEmailId);

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "OnAuthorization : Invalid User : User does not exist",
                    StatusCode = 403
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**
For each controller action method, I would like to the Roles who can access the Api. In the below code snippet, Roles is an enum.
Basically, I am trying to implement the Role based access for each of the Api.

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles.Admin1,Roles.Admin2)]
```

**Issue:**
The CustomAuthorizeAttribute is getting called. But, the controller action is being invoked ir-respective of the Authentication within the CustomAuthorizeAttribute.

what is that I am missing here?

Comment: Have you registered `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` in Program.cs file? If you have, pls delete it.

Comment: @JasonPan No, I have not registered that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issue**

The problem is the method itself, you are using a call to an async method

```
var userDetails = await _userService.GetUserProfile(userEmailId);
```

That forced you to change to method signature to:

```
public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
```

Since the call to this method cannot be awaited (you cannot change it to `public async Task OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)`) the framework never executes the code after the `await` in time. The evaluation of `if (userDetails == null)` is not performed in time.

**Demonstration of the issue by providing a dirty fix**

If you change the line

```
var userDetails = await _userService.GetUserProfile(userEmailId);
```

to

```
var userDetails = _userService.GetUserProfile(userEmailId).Result;
```

you will notice the authentication is performed correctly. However, using `.Result` is not best practice and is not recommended. So either change `GetUserProfile` to a synchronous function or use an authorization mechanism that support Task based methods, allowing you to properly await methods.

**Solution**

There is an `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` interface that supports Task based methods, so use that one. It takes minimal code changes:

```cs
public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly Roles[] _roles;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(Roles[] roles, IUserService userService)
    {
        _roles = roles ?? throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("OnAuthorization : Missing role parameter");
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.HttpContext != null &&
            context.HttpContext.User != null &&
            context.HttpContext.User.Identity != null)
        {
            string? userEmailId = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmailId))
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "OnAuthorization : Invalid User : Email Id is not present",
                    StatusCode = 401
                };

                return;
            }

            var userDetails = await _userService.GetUserProfile(userEmailId);

            if (userDetails == null)
            {
                context.Result = new ContentResult()
                {
                    Content = "OnAuthorization : Invalid User : User does not exist",
                    StatusCode = 403
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do mind: in .Net Core there are new ways introduced to perform authorization, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For example, you could use Policy Based or Role Based authorization that also natively supports [Task based methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationhandler.handleasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-iauthorizationhandler-handleasync(microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-authorizationhandlercontext)) allowing you to use async methods in your custom policies.

References

- [Custom policy example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0#parameterized-authorize-attribute-example)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/932728